# How to store and retrieve a dictionary of tuples in config parser python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, configparser

I'm using the [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) library in python to manage my configuration files.

But, I can't find a method to store and retrieve tuples data-structure through it.

My data is a dictionary of tuples.

```
name_mapper = {
    0 = (0, 0)
    1 = (0, 1)
    2 = (0, 2)
    3 = (1, 0)
    4 = (1, 1)
    5 = (1, 2)
    6 = (2, 0)
    7 = (2, 1)
    8 = (2, 2)
    9 = (3, 0)
    10 = (3, 1)
    11 = (3, 2)
}
```

When I write this dictionary via configparser, everything becomes a string.

**myconfig.ini**

```
[NAME_MAPPER]
0 = (0, 0)
1 = (0, 1)
2 = (0, 2)
3 = (1, 0)
4 = (1, 1)
5 = (1, 2)
6 = (2, 0)
7 = (2, 1)
8 = (2, 2)
9 = (3, 0)
10 = (3, 1)
11 = (3, 2)
```

Now, on reading the *"my_config.ini"*

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config_params.ini')
name_mapper = dict(config['NAME_MAPPER'])
```

But, the dictionary no longer holds tuples, its just tuple formatted as string.

```
name_mapper = {
    '0' = '(0, 0)'
    '1' = '(0, 1)'
    '2' = '(0, 2)'
    '3' = '(1, 0)'
    '4' = '(1, 1)'
    '5' = '(1, 2)'
    '6' = '(2, 0)'
    '7' = '(2, 1)'
    '8' = '(2, 2)'
    '9' = '(3, 0)'
    '10' = '(3, 1)'
    '11' = '(3, 2)'
}
```

I figured out a way to correct this by using ast.literal_eval method.

```
from ast import literal_eval

new_name_mapper = dict()
for each in name_mapper:
    new_name_mapper[int(each)] = literal_eval(name_mapper[each])
```

Now, *new_name_mapper* is correctly formatted.

```
name_mapper = {
    0 = (0, 0)
    1 = (0, 1)
    2 = (0, 2)
    3 = (1, 0)
    4 = (1, 1)
    5 = (1, 2)
    6 = (2, 0)
    7 = (2, 1)
    8 = (2, 2)
    9 = (3, 0)
    10 = (3, 1)
    11 = (3, 2)
}
```

But I'm sure, its not the best approach. Anyone got better & more pythonic ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Config parser will always return Strings, except you use an explicit converter using the `getbool` getint`` etc methods. However you can write your own converter function and register it with your parser, then use it to retrieve the value any way you like.

From the [Configparser Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#customizing-parser-behaviour):

> converters, default value: not set
>
> Config parsers provide option value getters that perform type conversion. By default getint(), getfloat(), and getboolean() are implemented. Should other getters be desirable, users may define them in a subclass or pass a dictionary where each key is a name of the converter and each value is a callable implementing said conversion. For instance, passing {'decimal': decimal.Decimal} would add getdecimal() on both the parser object and all section proxies. In other words, it will be possible to write both parser_instance.getdecimal('section', 'key', fallback=0) and parser_instance['section'].getdecimal('key', 0).
>
> If the converter needs to access the state of the parser, it can be implemented as a method on a config parser subclass. If the name of this method starts with get, it will be available on all section proxies, in the dict-compatible form (see the getdecimal() example above).

So you could write a function to parse the tuple

```
 >>> def parse_tuple(input):
 ...     return tuple(k.strip() for k in input[1:-1].split(','))

 >>> parse_tuple('(1, 2, 3)')
 >>> ('1', '2', '3')
```

or if you want ints:

```
 >>> def parse_int_tuple(input):
 ...     return tuple(int(k.strip()) for k in input[1:-1].split(','))

 >>> parse_int_tuple('(1, 2, 3)')
 >>> (1, 2, 3)
```

the create your configparser object, passing this converter:

```
>>> parser = ConfigParser(converters={'tuple': parse_int_tuple})
>>> parser.read_dict({'NAME_MAPPER': name_mapper})
>>> parser['NAME_MAPPER'].gettuple('0')
(0, 0)
```

IMO this is the most *pythonic* approach since it uses only well documented functionality